# Problems with new Apple ID for a macOS installation

Tags: macos, install, apple-id

My friend gave me an old macOS (El Capitan). I formatted the disk and created a new Apple ID online. When I tried to log in to continue the reinstallation of the OS, it says that the Apple ID is not used in the App Store. I don't have any iPhone or other Apple products, only this "new" MacBook Pro.

Comment: Did you actually format the hard drive, or simply reinstall macOS over the previous install?

Comment: I formatted it using disk utility

Comment: I believe, it's possible to skip Apple ID login during installation. You can login after installation.

Comment: When i click install to a hard drive it shows that it needed to log in an account, this is the first time i use a macbook pro

Comment: Are you trying to install El Capitan or a newer version of macOS? According to Apple's [support page](https://support.apple.com/HT204904), your Mac may still be associated with your friend's Apple ID.